# Deleting duplicate rows in MS ACCESS

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am making a table by combining columns of two tables. But there are few duplicate rows also. How do you delete duplicate rows from MS Access. I tried using the duplicate record query and also tried to use append query. But neither of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can do this without using the Access wizards:
1. Run a Make Table Query and in the select statement use grouping for every column. If the tables have a unique ID, don't use the ID because that will make every record unique
2. Export a Select query with the columns you want from the two tables to an Excel workbook. Once in Excel go to the Data tab and click on the column header selector and click on the Remove Duplicates button. Make sure you expand the selection if it asks you. Then save and link the Excel Workbook to Access again and do whatever you need to do from there

There are more ways, but you'd have to provide more details as to what you're trying to accomplish